# How To Optimize Query Of Lists Against Lists

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm building an app using Xamarin.Forms, and I'm running into a really slow query in the data that I need to optimize if possible.

In order to understand the question I'm trying to frame, I need to do a good job of explaining the database relationships. The business software I'm trying to build allows the user to schedule employees onto crews and crews onto job operations. For the purposes of this explanation, we can ignore jobs, even though the database objects include 'job' in their name.

For scheduling employees day by day, I created a kanban that allows the user to drag employee names to the crew that they want to schedule them onto for the day, and when they are finished editing they use toolbar buttons to navigate to the next date they want to schedule. In the background, the code is creating database objects that create the link between an employee, a date, and a crew.

For scheduling operations day by day, I created a side-scrolling gantt-style scheduler that allows the user to drag operation blocks onto a crew for the day. In the background, the code is creating database objects that create the link between an operation, a date and a crew.

Here's a simple version of what the database objects look like.

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    long? Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Password { get; set; }
}
```

```
public interface ICrewMember
{
    long? Id { get; set; }
    IEmployee Employee { get; set; }
    bool IsLeader { get; set; }
    ICrew Crew { get; set; }
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

```
public interface IJobSchedule
{
    long? Id { get; set; }
    IOperation Operation { get; set; }
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    ICrew Crew { get; set; }
}
```

```
public interface IOperation
{
    long? Id { get; set; }
    int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

So the complexity of the scenario comes when I want to find what operations an employee has been scheduled for. I have to first query to find the employee's schedule objects, create a list of crews/dates that they've been schedule for, then get a list of the job schedules that match the date/crew list, and then boil it down to a distinct list of operations (since an operation could get scheduled across multiple days). Here's my current code to do this:

```
public async Task<List<IOperation>> GetOperationsByEmployee(IDataService<IJobSchedule> JobScheduleRepository)
{
    JobScheduleRepository = JobScheduleRepository ??
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(JobScheduleRepository));

    var result = new List<IOperation>();

    var empSchedMatches = await GetEmployeeSchedules().ConfigureAwait(false);

    var jobSchedules = await GetJobSchedules(JobScheduleRepository, empSchedMatches).ConfigureAwait(false);

    result = jobSchedules.Select(x => x.Operation).Distinct().ToList();

    return result;
}
```

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<ICrewMember>> GetEmployeeSchedules()
{
    //Get complete list of employee schedules to sort through
    var allEmpSched = await CrewMemberRepository.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    //Get schedules with date greater than or equal to Date for this employee
    var empSchedMatches = allEmpSched.Where(x => x.Date >= Date && x.Employee == Employee);
    return empSchedMatches;
}
```

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<IJobSchedule>> GetJobSchedules(IDataService<IJobSchedule> JobScheduleRepository, IEnumerable<ICrewMember> employeeSchedules)
{
    //Get complete list of job schedules to sort through
    var allJobSched = await JobScheduleRepository.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    allJobSched = allJobSched.Where(x => x.Date >= Date && x.Crew != null && x.Operation != null);
    int count = allJobSched.Count();


    var result = new List<IJobSchedule>();

    foreach (var empSched in employeeSchedules)
    {
        //For each employee schedule, there should be 1 matching job schedule
        //if the crew was assigned a job for that day
        var matches = allJobSched.Where(x => x.Date == empSched.Date && x.Crew == empSched.Crew);
        result.AddRange(matches);

        string message = $"GetJobSchedules() comparing ({count}) Job Schedules " +
            $"to empSched.{empSched.Id} crew.{empSched.Crew.Id} date.{empSched.Date:M/d}";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In order to try to view the process, I had added in a number of different bits of code that printed the steps to the debugger, including a stopwatch. Here's the debugger output:

```
[0:] Method Called: GetOperationsByEmployee
[0:] GetOperationsByEmployee() executing query...
[0:] Method Called: GetEmployeeSchedules
[0:] Method Called: GetJobSchedules
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.17196 crew.3 date.2/6
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.18096 crew.3 date.2/4
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.18221 crew.3 date.2/3
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.18902 crew.3 date.2/7
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.21243 crew.3 date.1/27
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.21321 crew.3 date.1/28
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.21360 crew.3 date.1/29
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.21399 crew.3 date.1/30
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.21438 crew.3 date.1/31
[0:] GetJobSchedules() comparing (51) Job Schedules to empSched.21528 crew.3 date.2/5
[0:] Data loaded 6391 ms
```

So when I'm running the app using mock data, with like 10 objects in memory, it runs in ~100 ms. When I've got 50,000 objects in the real database, with 30 employees, 10 crews, 500 jobs, and 1500 operations to sort through, it takes ~7,000 ms. That comparison was probably obvious, but the point is that I need to find some way, if possible, to optimize the query. I'd like to get it closer to 1 second load time if it can be done.

As always, thanks for any help!

**Edit**

I'm afraid I'm not getting the answers I was hoping for, because I'm not really looking for advice on the data access side of the question, I'm looking for advice on the LINQ side of the question. I don't know if it helps to understand the data access scenario, so I'll explain briefly.

I'm coding in Xamarin.Forms, using [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) as my dependency injector. I'm trying to use interfaces to allow the calls to the data service to be abstracted from the data service.

The data is being stored in SQL Server on a server here at the office. The app is using an API for SQL to SQLite called [Zumero](https://zumero.com/). Zumero syncs the requested tables off the SQL Server and deposits them into a local file on the mobile device.

I'm using [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) to serve the data to the program, again by using interfaces and field mapping to try to abstract the calls for the database objects apart from the database objects themselves.

**Edit 2**

I'm going to try to re-ask the question here so that it becomes more clear what I'm looking for:

I have a SQLite file that has employees, operations, daily employee schedules, and daily operation schedules. What are some ways that I could write a query to get an employee's list of operations that they've been schedule for?

Imaginary Question:

> What are Bob's currently scheduled operations?

Imaginary rows in the data tables:

1. Employees

   1. Bob
   2. Jim
   3. Larry
2. Employee Schedules

   1. Bob 1/1/2020 Concrete Crew 1
   2. Bob 1/2/2020 Concrete Crew 1
   3. Bob 1/3/2020 Mill Crew 2
3. Operation Schedules

   1. Crew 1 1/1/2020 Concrete Operation 1
   2. Crew 2 1/1/2020 Mill Operation 1
   3. Crew 1 1/2/2020 Concrete Operation 1
   4. Crew 1 1/3/2020 Concrete Operation 3
4. Operations

   1. Concrete Operation 1
   2. Mill Operation 1
   3. Concrete Operation 3

Desired Result:

> Bob currently has the following operations on the schedule: Concrete Operation 1

It's a relational database question, of sorts, because I'm asking about the best way to figure out the link from employees through employee schedules through operation schedules to operations.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're not getting the answers you would like because you're not using the tools properly, and you apparently (based on your edit) are not willing to adopt proper use of the tools.  This query would make perfect sense as a SELECT...JOIN statement in SQL and would probably return the data in <10 milliseconds.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How could I use a SQL query in this scenario? (Xamarin Forms, SQLite local mobile device file) It feels a bit like you didn't actually read my question before you suggested that I'm not willing to adopt proper use of the tools.

Comment: I read your whole question, painful as it was. I gather that you have a database, and you have a few queries to get data out of that database. What I also deduced is that you have a query that is not programmed into your data access logic. Hence, you're using Linq as a hammer when in fact you need a screwdriver.

Comment: I put an exhaustive question explanation because I thought it might be helpful to anyone who wanted to understand what I was asking and why. It seems like I might have put too much on, because the things that people are focusing on is what I've already done, and the problems with my code `Repository.GetAllItemsAsync()`. What I'm hoping to see is someone looking at the database relationships: Employees -- schedules -- schedules -- Operations, and suggest a way to get from point A to point D.

Comment: Also, you've probably come across one of the main reasons why I don't use ORM tools (which is what EF is).

Comment: I can't teach you how to use these tools via a single question/answer. I am telling you to look up how to do it in the database. Or, ask a new, more specific question on how to get data out of your database. Right now your question is how to filter it once you've got the data... I answered that below. But it's not the right question.

Comment: I apologize if you see this as being overly-critical - I am being critical, but not out of spite or insincerity. I just saw several answers trying to point you down the right path, and in spite of that, I see reluctance to heed their advice.

Comment: After your edit, you're missing the definition for `ICrew`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the question asked.

**Question 1: How do I write the code to get from one to many to many to one?**

I didn't get any answers here. I'll re-post the code I'm using.

```
public async Task<List<IOperation>> GetOperationsByEmployee(
    IDataService<IJobSchedule> JobScheduleRepository, 
    DateTime Date, 
    IEmployee Employee)
{
    var result = new List<IOperation>();

    var empSchedMatches = allEmployeeSchedules.Where(x => x.Date >= Date && x.Employee == Employee);

    var jobSchedules = new List<IJob>();

    foreach (var empSched in empSchedMatches)
    {
        var matches = allJobSched.Where(x => x.Date == empSched.Date && x.Crew == empSched.Crew);
        jobSchedules.AddRange(matches);
    }

    result = jobSchedules.Select(x => x.Operation).Distinct().ToList();

    return result;
}
```

**Question 2: How do I speed up this query?**

I got a bit of haranguing over ORM choice here, but I didn't have any concrete implementation steps to improve the code. Then, I had a conversation with a programmer who explained to me that he has a ton of experience using Entity Framework with SQLite. He gave me a couple of concrete pointers, and a code sample for how to improve the database loading speed. He explained that Entity Framework tracks objects that it loads, but if the operation is reading data that doesn't need to be tracked, the loading speed can be improved by turning off the tracking. He gave me the following code sample.

```
internal class ReadOnlyEFDatabase : EFDatabase
{
    public ReadOnlyEFDatabase(string dbPath, DbContextOptions options) : base(dbPath, options)
    {
        this.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        this.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    }
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        throw new Exception("Attempting to save changes from a read-only connection to the database.");
    }
}
```

Thanks to Jeremy Sheeley from [zumero](https://zumero.com) for this help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, you are creating entire tables to runtime and matching them via C# and it is wrong.

This is what database is made for and you must use it.

You have many choices, queries, views, stored procedures, but for sure asking the entire db and performing matches via code is a wrong way.

Comment: I added an edit to explain the situation better. From my very limited understanding of EF Core DbSet<> queries, they return an IEnumerable, which means it's a deferred loading query against the data set. If that means what I thought it means, I can extend the specificity of the query by adding filtering criteria before calling the execution of the query. This is what I thought I was doing in the code, hence my edit that I don't know how to improve the use of EF / SQLite.

Comment: Once you perform the enumeration they load it so you lose that "bonus"

Comment: Right. So if you follow the flow of code, I'm not performing the enumeration until after I've added the date / crew criteria. So am I missing something? Doesn't that mean I'm getting the "bonus?"

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid answer or makes more sense as a comment, but it's exactly correct.

Comment: You could probably write the best Linq-to-entities query in the world, and EF Core is going to make a huge mess out of it and turn what should be a <10 millisecond data call into a 1-2 second monstrosity. And then you'll spend the rest of whatever time you may or may not have saved configuring EF core trying to come up with the exact right sequence to make it perform better.

Comment: I suppose you can tell that I'm hesitant to take the weeks of learning how to use EF and Zumero and toss them. Can you give me some specific suggestions about how you would do things better?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that you could do to speed up your query. There is one obvious change that I would implement(if I understand the flow enough):

```
//change to something where you pass your parameters as to not need to load all of your jobs every time
var allJobSched = await JobScheduleRepository.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
//change to 
var matchingJobSched = await JobScheduleRepository.FindMatchingJobSchedules(DateTime date, int crewId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You seem to be doing this for each object, so this refactor should be done over all of your code.

Something else you could try is to write a stored procedure for this action and leave the ORM-time out.

Answer (score 0):

At least from the way I am reading this you are doing a lot of queries where you're essentially fetching the whole set of data from your database before querying in memory. This works fine if you have a few records as you've discovered, however if your front loading whole tables every request you're going to find yourself completely bottlenecked, to the point where your appliacation will eventually cease to function entirely.

There's a lot of code here but just as an example.

```
    var allJobSched = await JobScheduleRepository.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
allJobSched = allJobSched.Where(x => x.Date >= Date && x.Crew != null && x.Operation != null);
int count = allJobSched.Count();
```

In the above snippet first you pull all of the Job schedules from the database this will invariably involve a large over the wire data pull from your database (not good).

You'd be much better if you write something similar to the following.

```
    var jobs= await JobScheduleRepository.GetValidJobsAfterDate(Date);
```

The implementation of the query itself should be sent by your repostitory to your database an handled there, you should never be pulling back huge collections of data to work from in memory (in most cases).

Answer (score -1):

IF, as you insist, this must be done 100% in LINQ, which I do not recommend as you need to do a better job pre-filtering the data coming in, then your issue is that you are performing an exhaustive search for every row in the table.  Instead, I recommend creating a dictionary and first loading your rows into that.

Instead of:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<ICrewMember>> GetEmployeeSchedules()
{
    //Get complete list of employee schedules to sort through
    var allEmpSched = await CrewMemberRepository.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    //Get schedules with date greater than or equal to Date for this employee
    var empSchedMatches = allEmpSched.Where(x => x.Date >= Date && x.Employee == Employee);
    return empSchedMatches;
}
```

Do this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Employee, List<IJobSchedule>>
foreach(var item in allEmpSched) {
  if (dict.TryGetValue(item.Employee, out var schedules)) {
    schedules.Add(item)
  } else {
    dict[item.Employee] = new List<IJobSchedule>() { item };
  }
}
```

Then, using that dictionary, look up your employee. That's essentially what the database will do for you automatically if you have a properly configured index along with an appropriate SELECT clause, but there you go.

**Edit:**  I see that you're hoping to maybe relocate this to the ORM, such that it will write the correct SQL for you. I don't know how to do that, because I don't use ORMs.

**Why don't I use ORMs?** There are three reasons. First, data access is not something that should be given over to a machine to build into your application. Data access is often the most-used code you'll have in the software package. Pay attention to it and design it well. Computers cannot provide an effective substitute for proper design.

Second, the SQL language itself is an abstraction upon the physical means to access the underlying data. When a SQL query is executed, the first thing that the database engine does is to come up with a plan to execute it. In essence, the SQL is being interpreted and compiled down to generated code. If you throw another code generator on top of it (the ORM), the results are naturally going to vary, and rarely does an ORM produce good results without spending quite a bit of time tweaking.  Spend your time writing good SQL queries.

Finally, ORMs don't really eliminate the problem of impedance mismatch between strong object-oriented models and a relational database. You have to start by addressing the problem in the data model itself, and write your code to deal with relational objects, not deeply-nested objects. Once you do this, you'll find that writing your own queries isn't really that hard.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestion. I know SO points out that the comments is not a place for an extended discussion, but I'm trying to learn what I can here, so thanks for understanding. I thought that the way EF worked, it has a connection to the db (a SQLite file in this case) and writing LINQ queries against EF's DbSet<> would be turned into a type of SQL query against the SQLite file. This is why I was coding under the impression that using LINQ against EF should have been similar in speed to using SQL against a server. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hopefully someone else can answer there. I think you should ask that as a separate question - specifically, where did you go wrong. I don’t use the tools, preferring instead to write good SQL queries that then can be further trimmed down with good LINQ queries.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the code that was distracting, so hopefully it will be more clear what I was trying to ask. Thanks for the time you've already taken to read through and offer suggestions. My perspective is as a self-taught programmer, and I'm only a couple of weeks into learning about how to use EF, so you're talking way above my head with the explanations about ORM and SQL. I'll try to do some research to understand it all better.

Comment: @NateW - start by defining your data. What is it that you need to store? What relationships are there among these entities? Does it make sense as a relational model in the first place? This is why programmers make so much money - these are hard questions to answer. Starting out, it is very intimidating. You're doing stuff that people 3-5 years into their career struggle with. Don't feel bad about it - there is a steep learning curve here.